# Error with color package and \AtBeginDocument in cls file

Tags: color, preamble, bugs

I have `myclass.cls` with the following content:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}
\LoadClass{article}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \tableofcontents
  \clearpage
}
\endinput
```

I also have `mydoc.tex` in the same folder with the following content:

```
\documentclass{myclass}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
  mydocument
\end{document}
```

Compiling gives me the error

> Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}.

It would be fine if I do any of the following:

- move `\AtBeginDocument{...}` to `mydoc.tex`
- remove `\tableofcontents`
- remove `\clearpage`
- remove `\usepackage{color}`

Is this a bug?

Comment: please show the actual error from `!` to `?` from the log file in a code block in the question, the form you show is just a misleading summary from your editor which does not show which command is undefined

Answer (score 5):

From the LaTeX Companion, 2nd edition, to `\AtBeginDocument`:

> Note, however, that code in the `\AtBeginDocument` hook is part of the
>   preamble. Thus, restrictions limit what can be put there; in
>   particular, no typesetting can be done.

A better hook is provided as `\AfterEndPreamble` of package `etoolbox`, which is executed at the very end of `\begin{document}`, after the `\AtBeginDocument` stuff.

Short example as standalone file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndPreamble{
  \tableofcontents
  \clearpage
}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello World}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\set@color ...\@pdfcolorstack push{\current@color 
                                                  }\aftergroup \reset@color 
l.3 \begin{document}

?
```

That is `\current@color` which is not yet defined as colour (as well as fonts and many other things) are set up in `\begin{document}` and `\AtBeginDocument` is mainly aimed for loading *preamble* commands at the end of the preamble, it can not reliably be used for typesetting commands as it is executed too early.